# Does a square-integrable function always verify $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x(t)| \ dt < \infty$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

It is proven that for a [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) $X(i\omega)$ defined by the following generalised integral:

$$X(i\omega) =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) e^{-i\omega t} \ dt \tag{1}$$

the reversed transformation:

$$\hat x(t) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(i\omega) e^{i\omega t} \ d\omega \tag{2}$$

convergences [quadraticaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#quadratic_convergence) to $x(t)$ if $x$ is a [square-integrable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-integrable_function):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x(t)|^2 \ dt < \infty \tag{3}$$

However, the quadratic convergences does not guarantee thta $x(t) = \hat x(t) \ \forall t$. In order to be certain of that, the function $x$ also needs to [converge absolutely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence):

\begin{equation}
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x(t)| \ dt < \infty 
  \tag{4}
\end{equation}

I wonder if there is a link between equations $(3)$ and $(4)$. I already have a counter-example showing that $(3) \not \Rightarrow (4)$, but I couldn't prove so far that $(4) \not \Rightarrow (3)$

Comment: For the reverse direction, use the counter example of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ with its singularity near the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and as a hint, note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is in $L^1((0,1))$, but not in $L^2((0,1))$. (btw, if the bounds are finite, then (3) does imply (4))

However, the claim you make can only hold a.e in general because we’re not dealing with continuous functions.

Anyway, Fourier’s inversion theorem holds in the $L^1$ case as well: it tells us that if $x\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$, and $X\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$, then $x=\hat{x}$ pointwise a.e (so in particular, there is a continuous function which is equal to $x$ a.e).

Comment: …your notation for the Fourier transform was completely different from the standard ones I was used to hence the erroneous (nitpicky) remark, and edits

Comment: I didn't understand what edits you were refering to, but thanks for the answer ! You say that $x, X \in L^1$ is sufficiant, but does $x \in L^2$ imply $X \in L^1$ ? It would be preferable to know wether $x$ converges or not without explicitly computing $X$

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg no that is not true, and unfortunately that's one of the limitations of this version of the Fourier inversion theorem. But, you can generalize the Fourier transform to the setting of tempered distributions, and there, it is an isomorphism (it is also an isomorphism on $L^2$).